# Python, Javascript (PhantomJS) server side communication

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs

What would be a good way for my .py and .js scripts to communicate? The .js script is executed via PhantomJS (or Casper) and both are server side.

Ideally, the Python script would send some parameters to the .js script, the .js script would do its thing, and then the .js script would send the results back to the Python script. It would also be OK if the .js script made the results available somewhere, but not necessarily to the original Python call.

My issue is not so much the data format (HTML/JSON etc.), but the actual communication.

I'm not interested in using Selenium because of issues I have had with high memory usage.

EDIT:

The question is not about scraping. I am going to be using PhantomJS for that. PhantomJS runs a little program, which is written in javascript. It has a .js extension. Presumably I have access to all javascript functions.  Python is 2.7

Comment: python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I would use `import urllib` and the `urlopen` function and communicate via the server, maybe.

Comment: The problem that I have is to understand the role of phyntom js. Could you explain that?

Comment: I tried to explain a bit more.

Comment: Two things that come to my mind are: Use http://nodejs.org/ as the javascript server or use Websockets+json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839054/websocket-server-in-python